# Trouble using PHP and MySQL to see if a user exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have already looked at various other SO answers and still cannot get this to work. I know that my `summonerid` get's through fine as I can echo it back. I also can reach my MySQL table, so it has to be my query syntax.

```
$query="SELECT FROM UserTable (summonerid) WHERE summonerid='$usersummonerid'";
if(mysql_num_rows($query)<1) 
{
   //register name
} else {
   //name exists already
}
```

The errors I am getting back

> **Warning**:  mysql_query(): No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it.  in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\GVLegends\Scripts\check.php** on line
>   **21**
>  
>  **Warning**:  mysql_query(): A link to the
>   server could not be established in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\GVLegends\Scripts\check.php** on line
>   **21**
>  
>  **Warning**:  mysql_num_rows() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\GVLegends\Scripts\check.php** on line
>   **22**

Here is my entire PHP for context (sorry if it seems poorly coded, I am newer to PHP)

```
<?php
//login details

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$username = $_POST['user'];
$userpassword = $_POST['pass'];
$usersummoner = $_POST['summoner'];
$usersummonerid = $_POST['summonerid'];
$useremail = $_POST['email'];

$query="SELECT FROM UserTable (summonerid) WHERE summonerid='$usersummonerid'";
if(mysql_num_rows($query)<1) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO UserTable (name, password, summonerid, summonername,email)
  VALUES ('$username', '$userpassword', '$usersummonerid', '$usersummoner',$useremail')";
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo '{"success":true}';
  } else {
    echo '{"success":false}';
  }
} else {
  echo '{"success":false}';
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` function as they are deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: try `$query="SELECT summonerid FROM UserTable WHERE summonerid='$usersummonerid'";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT FROM UserTable (summonerid) WHERE summonerid='$usersummonerid'";
if(mysql_num_rows($query)<1) {...}
```

Where exactly are you executing this query? Besides the horrendous security issues, all you're doing is defining a string

`mysql_num_rows()` expects the result of an executed query as its argument, not simply a PHP string value.... you need to **execute** the query that you have defined in your string to get a result

Comment: sorry I am new to PHP, it is in a protected Scripts folder. I am doing an AngularJS callback to see if the summoner (name) exists or not. :/